# PhpStorm: debugging session hangs browser and doesn't break at breakpoints

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to debug a CakePHP application with PhpStorm.
Basically:

1. following the instructions I installed the `xdebug` plugin on both dev machine and browser
2. created a `PHP Demote Debug` configuration
3. start the server as usual (`bin/cake server -H 0.0.0.0`)
4. run the debug configuration (that enable the listening for incoming connections)
5. enable the debug mode in the `xdebug` plugin and reload the page
6. PhpStorm "breaks" the execution (I enabled the option to break at first line)
7. in the Debug panel it opens the "index.php" file and the browser cannot load the page until I press a lot of times F9 (resume). Then every link I click on the application leads to the same behavior: I need to press F9 multiple times to go ahead.

But no code is shown nor the breakpoints are catch.
Index.php is also the oly file that have the "bug" icon in the Debug panel.

I guess it received the incoming connection, in fact if I don't resume the debug the browser cannot load the page. But this behavior is far away from a "debugging session".

I surely miss something important.
Please feel free to ask in the comments other information you need.

Comment: Have you gone through [this troubleshooting page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html)?

Comment: Your `index.php` must be your entry point script. It may be called multiple times (e.g. for not found resources etc - e.g. missing favicon.ico is the most common reason). In any case --- enable Xdebug log and dig into it to see what file is called etc.

Comment: Actually, enabling the logs and restart the debugging session did the trick (weird...)